# def create function with many2one fields in odoo 10, python

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-10

I would like to define my name depends on my asset tags plus my asset brand but my asset tag and asset brand fields is Many2one and it doesn't give me an error but the output is wrong. It gives me a number, integer instead of a string(which is the tag name plus the brand name). My expected result is for example my asset tag is Computer, then my asset brand is Asus then my expected result in name would be Computer-Asus. Please help. Many thanks.

This is what i do.

```
@api.model
def create(self,vals):
    if vals['asset_tag']:
        asset_tag = vals['asset_tag']
    else:
        asset_tag = ''

    if vals['asset_brands_id']:
        brand_id = vals['asset_brands_id']
    else:
        brand_id = ''

    name = "{}-{}".format(asset_tag, brand_id)

    vals['name'] = name
    return super(ModifiedAssetAsset, self).create(vals)
```

then the output is this

[image: result]

It gives me 2-4 on my asset name but my expecting result is Vehicle-Toyota

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Please try this code it help you

```
@api.model
def create(self,vals):
    if vals['asset_tag']:
        asset_tag = vals['asset_tag']
    else:
        asset_tag = ''

    if vals['asset_brands_id']:
        brand_id=self.env['asset.brand.model.name'].search([('id','=',vals
                 ['asset_brands_id'])],limit=1).name
    else:
        brand_id = ''
        name = "{}-{}".format(asset_tag, brand_id)
        vals['name'] = name
        return super(ModifiedAssetAsset, self).create(vals)@api.model
```

Comment: whoooa. It works master :) Thank you so much! Finally. I will go next to def write anw Thanks again.

Comment: can you explain for what is the attributes limit=1?

Comment: I search a lot but I didn't find it in google or in some module in odoo anw thanks again :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice :) Anw I am new in odoo.